# What is the syntax of filtering an array per element value?

Tags: ios, combine

**Scenario:** I'm trying to use less post-data processing versus in-stream filtering.
I want to filter out zeroed items from a long data stream (array).

**Problem:** I don't know how to read the '$0' placeholder to determine the available elements to filter.

Here's what I'm getting:
[image]

Here's a code snippet:

```
struct CanadaDataListElement: Codable {
    let updated: Int
    let province: String
    let date: String
    let todayCases, todayTests, todayRecovered, todayDeaths: Int
    let cases, active, tests, recovered: Int
    let deaths: Int
}

typealias CanadaDataList = [CanadaDataListElement]

...

func getData() {
    let str = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/gov/Canada?allowNull=false"
    let url = URL(string: str)!
    let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map(\.data)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .filter { $0.CanadaDataListElement.tests != 0 }
        .decode(type: CanadaDataList.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
      ...
```

I looks like the filter is working on raw data, hence this may not be the right place for it.

So I moved the .filter *to after the* **.decode**.

I put in an index of '1' to see if I got anything.

[image]

This should be an easy fix once I know the correct syntax for filtering out data with a zeroed member.

Here's some of the data.  There are a lot of elements; hence I want to filter out ones with zero (0) cases (and/or) tests.

```
(lldb) po someValue 
▿ 4017 elements
  ▿ 0 : CanadaDataListElement
    - updated : 1606752145723
    - province : "Ontario"
    - date : "31-01-2020"
    - todayCases : 3
    - todayTests : 0
    - todayRecovered : 0
    - todayDeaths : 0
    - cases : 3
    - active : 3
    - tests : 0
    - recovered : 0
    - deaths : 0
  ▿ 1 : CanadaDataListElement
  ...
```

**Question:** What is the correct syntax for filter data per element value?

Comment: The syntax `$0[1].cases > 0; return true` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The order is wrong: First `decode` the data then `filter` the result.

```
func getData() {
    let str = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/gov/Canada?allowNull=false"
    let url = URL(string: str)!
    let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map(\.data)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .decode(type: CanadaDataList.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .filter { $0.tests > 0 }

    
  ...
```

Comment: 'CanadaDataList' is a type alias of an array: typealias CanadaDataList = [CanadaDataListElement]

Comment: How should one know that?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question to include that in the code.

Comment: That’s not a List. That’s an Array.